# AWS : Invalid identity pool configuration. Check assigned IAM roles for this pool

Tags: javascript, angularjs, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-cognito

I have created one user pool & identity pool.

I have used javascript sdk.

I am able to signup, send confirmation code & confirm user successfully with javascript sdk.

But when i try to sign in user with authenticate method & try to get credentials with "CognitoIdentityCredentials" by passing idToken with below code

```
logins[cognitoEndpoint + "/" + userPoolId] = jwtToken;

    AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
      IdentityPoolId: identityPoolId,
      Logins: logins
    });
```

it's giving me below error

```
Error: Invalid identity pool configuration. Check assigned IAM roles for this pool.
    at Request.extractError (aws-sdk.js:104063)
    at Request.callListeners (aws-sdk.js:106060)
    at Request.emit (aws-sdk.js:106034)
    at Request.emit (aws-sdk.js:105121)
    at Request.transition (aws-sdk.js:104843)
    at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (aws-sdk.js:108480)
    at aws-sdk.js:108492
    at Request.<anonymous> (aws-sdk.js:104859)
    at Request.<anonymous> (aws-sdk.js:105123)
    at Request.callListeners (aws-sdk.js:106070)
```

I have given administrator access to "Unauthenticated role" & "Unauthenticated role"  of identity pool and to user whose credentials i am using.

I am new to aws. Can anyone tell me what am i missing?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 119, accepted):

Check that the role you have assigned in Cognito Identity Pools (Federated Identities), has a trust relationship with the identity pool.

**Get the identity pool ID + the name of the role that isn't working**. To do this:

- Go to Cognito
- Select Manage Federated Identities
- Select the identity pool
- Click Edit identity pool (top right)
- Make a note of the identity pool ID
- Make a note of the name of the role that isn't working (e.g. Cognito_blahUnauth_Role

In IAM, check the trust relationship for the role. **Ensure that the StringEquals condition value matches the identity pool ID**.

To do this:

- Go to IAM
- Click Roles
- Click the name of the role that you noted previously
- Click Trust relationships
- On the right under Conditions, check the StringEquals condition contains the identity pool Id that you noted previously.

**Edit the trust relationship to fix.**

Comment: this, thanks. I had forgotten to add this when setting up my cloud formation script

Comment: That solved my problem. I had put identity pool name instead of pool id. Thank you.

Comment: I would give you 100+ for this answer if I could.
Setup of Users, Groups, Roles, Policies through Cognito and IAM is far from straightforward. Have spent three days on this issue!

Comment: I could kiss you, @AlexHague.  In my case I had reused an IAM role for another identity pool, and had forgotten about this step.  My IAM role only had a trust relationship with the old identity pool.  I wish this would answer would have come up in my first Google search instead of four days later.

Comment: This helped !! Thanks.

Comment: Can't thank you enough! I changed the region so the identity pool as correct but not the region and this answer helped me find the error, thanks again!

Comment: Thanks! This comment helped me with a little error I had :)

Comment: Dude, I'll buy you a beer... Where did you get this workaround or where can I find more information about this? I've spent 8 hours on this, I'm about to crying

Comment: Thank you so much. I had gotten this erorr because I had deleted and recreated id pool, but reused the roles, which were pointing to the old identity pool id that i had deleted

Comment: Also, remember to include `sts:TagSession` in the IAM role’s trust policy when using "Attributes for access control" (Principal Tags). I had the same error message as in this thread, valid Trust policy according to this Answer, but missing `sts:TagSession` in the Trust Policy. CloudTrail was reporting "Unknown error" in my case, so it was tough to resolve, even Cognito Identity Pool "Edit" screen has a "Note" for that. Hope that helps someone.

Comment: Specifically, set `"Effect: Allow"` if it is currently in a `Deny` state. Thats what fixed it for me.

Answer (score 6):

I deactivated the `Claim mapping` inside `Identity pools > User access -> Identity Providers -> Attributes for access control -> Claim mapping` and worked again.

Comment: Thanks - This solve the issue where the is already populated correctly!

Comment: Sincerest thanks @csoria This has to be broken, after disabling claim mapping it works. But before I only had "default claim mapping"!! This is maddening.

Answer (score 3):

What you're trying to access here are "Cognito Federated Identity" credentials, which is a separate AWS product to "Cognito User Pools". In-order to retrieve these credentials, you need to connect your User Pool to your Federated Identity Pool.

Perhaps this link will help: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/amazon-cognito-integrating-user-pools-with-identity-pools.html

*Also, I would remove admin access from Unauthenticated permissions, it means anyone with your details has control of your AWS account.*

Answer (score 1):

When you create role in `IAM` and choose identity provider, make sure you don't choose user pool id, instead, you have to choose identity pool id.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using OpenID, disable attributes for access control and error will be gone

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue when I manually added additional roles in Cognito to the already existing. (previously created with amplify CLI)

**TLDR: Don't manually create groups and roles if you're going to be using them for Amplify.**

My accounts which had this error included the following attributes in that JWT. (you can go to [jwt.io](https://jwt.io/) and see your attributes)

```json
"cognito:roles": [
    "arn:aws:iam::*ACCOUNT_ID*:role/*THE_ROLE*"
  ],
"cognito:preferred_role": "arn:aws:iam::*ACCOUNT_ID*:role/*THE_ROLE*",
```

Then I found these roles and I tried to verify if they have correct conditions attached to them:

```json
"Condition": { "StringEquals": { "cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:aud": "us-west-2:<COGNITO_IDENTITY_POOL_ID>" }, "ForAnyValue:StringLike": { "cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:amr": "authenticated" } }
```

After a few hours of verifing the roles, configuring them it started finally working.

Lessons learned: *It's possible to fix them manually too.*

Then I manually deleted the groups in Cognito I've created along with the roles associated with them and then recreated it via the Amplify CLI from scratch. It worked like a charm. Apart from that in this way Amplify will maintains them, when I change configs etc.

Answer (score 0):

I had this error working with amplify. I noticed that the error appeared after I created Cognito User Roles from amplify cli. What I did was, delete these roles from CLI and create again from AWS Console and it worked fine!