# How to config AWS with cognito logins? - nodejs

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cognito, amazon-iam

I am trying to access s3 through Cognito logins.
This is how I config the AWS:

```
   AWS.config.update({
        region: 'us-west-2',
        userPoolId: "us-west-2*******1",
        userPoolWebClientId: "2******************n",
        credentials: new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
            IdentityPoolId: 'us-west-2:9**********2',
            Logins: {
                'cognito-idp.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/us-west-2*****1': idToken
            }
        })
    });
```

I got the following error:

```
Error uploading data:  { CredentialsError: Missing credentials in config
    at Request.extractError (/Users/lushali/code/nexus/scripts/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/protocol/json.js:51:27)
    at Request.callListeners (/Users/lushali/code/nexus/scripts/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:106:20)
    at Request.emit (/Users/lushali/code/nexus/scripts/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:78:10)
    at Request.emit (/Users/lushali/code/nexus/scripts/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:683:14)
    at Request.transition (/Users/lushali/code/nexus/scripts/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:22:10)
    at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (/Users/lushali/code/nexus/scripts/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:14:12)
    at /Users/lushali/code/nexus/scripts/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:26:10
    at Request.<anonymous> (/Users/lushali/code/nexus/scripts/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:38:9)
    at Request.<anonymous> (/Users/lushali/code/nexus/scripts/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:685:12)
    at Request.callListeners (/Users/lushali/code/nexus/scripts/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:116:18)
  message: 'Missing credentials in config',
  code: 'CredentialsError',
  time: 2019-03-14T17:22:59.631Z,
  requestId: 'd08fc55f-467d-11e9-8560-a1dcaac0f3ba',
  statusCode: 400,
  retryable: false,
  retryDelay: 72.65189640190827,
  originalError:
   { message: 'Could not load credentials from CognitoIdentityCredentials',
     code: 'CredentialsError',
     time: 2019-03-14T17:22:59.631Z,
     requestId: 'd08fc55f-467d-11e9-8560-a1dcaac0f3ba',
     statusCode: 400,
     retryable: false,
     retryDelay: 72.65189640190827,
     originalError:
      { message:
         'Invalid identity pool configuration. Check assigned IAM roles for this pool.',
        code: 'InvalidIdentityPoolConfigurationException',
        time: 2019-03-14T17:22:59.629Z,
        requestId: 'd08fc55f-467d-11e9-8560-a1dcaac0f3ba',
        statusCode: 400,
        retryable: false,
        retryDelay: 72.65189640190827 } } }
```

I searched the above error online, and I got some suggestions like checking the trust relationship. [[AWS : Invalid identity pool configuration. Check assigned IAM roles for this pool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44043289/aws-invalid-identity-pool-configuration-check-assigned-iam-roles-for-this-poo?rq=1) ]
This is what I currently have:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Federated": "cognito-identity.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity",
      "Condition": {
        "ForAnyValue:StringLike": {
          "cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:amr": "authenticated",
          "cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:aud": "us-west-2:9******2"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Is it still the problem of trust relationship? Please help, thanks!